# Split the column with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, sql-server-2012

I have the following output from a table and was wondering the best way to split the values into multiple rows.

**voucher    |               company    |

```
    InvoiceDescription**                   
VIV110175915    |          maec   |                   BOL013272-                              
VIV110174380    |          maec    |               BOL011927/BOL011929                         
VIV110174478     |         maec     |        BOL01256-, BOL012507-, BOL012508-
```

I need to trim the "InvoiceDescription" field  and duplicate the information over rows so the data would be as follows.

1. If InvoiceDescription = BOL011448- then return BOL011448 (removing the "-")
2. If InvoiceDescription = BOL011927/BOL011929 then return two rows one with BOL011927 and one with BOL011929 (removing the "/")
3. If InvoiceDescription = BOL01256-, BOL012507-, BOL012508- then return three rows one with BOL01256 and one with BOL012507 and one with BOL012508 (removing the "-")

**Output I wanted:**

```
voucher  |               company    |                  InvoiceDescription                  
VIV110175915    |          maec   |                   BOL013272                           
VIV110174380    |          maec    |                  BOL011927 
VIV110174380    |          maec    |                  BOL011929                        
VIV110174478     |         maec     |                 BOL01256
VIV110174478     |         maec     |                 BOL012507
VIV110174478     |         maec     |                 BOL012508
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 to setup these table and just need some help on how to split the subjects field up.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to do something by yourself?

Comment: YUCK!!! Delimited data violates 1NF and you have multiple delimiter characters. Do you have more than just , / and -? You are going to need to use a splitter to do this. Here is one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ And several other excellent options here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that does not require a TVF

```
Select A.[Voucher]
      ,A.[company]
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = replace(LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'))),'-','')
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(replace([InvoiceDescription],'/',','),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

You may notice I kept the Sequence, I find it useful from time-to-time.

**Returns**

```
Voucher         company RetSeq  RetVal
VIV110175915    maec    1       BOL013272
VIV110174380    maec    1       BOL011927
VIV110174380    maec    2       BOL011929
VIV110174478    maec    1       BOL01256
VIV110174478    maec    2       BOL012507
VIV110174478    maec    3       BOL012508
```